# Ошибка при подключении к удаленной БД MariaDb .NETCore

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, mariadb, mysqlconnector

При подключении к удаленной базе данных (MariaDb) столкнулся с ошибкой:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication with backend failed. Session will be closed.
```

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Использую MySql.Data и Dapper для получения данных из базы. Connection string для подключения генерируется с помощью MySqlConnectionStringBuilder следующим образом:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mySqlConnectionStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Server = internetApplicationsServer;
mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Port = internetApplicationsPort;
mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Database = internetApplicationsDatabase;
mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.UserID = internetApplicationsUserId;
mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Password = internetApplicationsPassword;
mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.CharacterSet = internetApplicationsCharset;
```

Данные для подключения проверял, совершенно точно корректные. Наткнулся в интернете на совет настроить default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password, однако не нашел такой возможности в MySqlConnector для .NET. Знаю, что в MySqlConnector для Python такая возможность имеется, используется аргумент auth_plugin. Подскажите, есть ли аналогичная возможность в C#? Или, может быть, имеются другие пути решения проблемы?

Comment: А соединение с этими вашими данными через консоль `mysql -uname -p` работает?

Comment: @Bulson да, работает. Проблема именно при подключении через код